# Const pointer to const

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following function prototype:

```
void PerformFusionCycle( StructType const* const a[],
                         StructType2 const* const b,
                         const float32 c,
                         StructType3 * const d,
                         StructType3 * const e)
```

I want to feed the function with values but I don't understand how to declare and give values to the first parameter. If I declare a variable exactly as the parameter needs to be, I cannot modify it's values, "not a modifiable lvalue" error appears. If I declare a variable so I can modify it's values, then I gen "incompatible types at argument #1" compiler error. How should I do this ?

Thanks !

Comment: *"Everything I use"* - Is also everything you didn't mention.

Comment: Actually, you should have no problem to feed this: const StructType* structArray[100];

Comment: C does not support constant arguments. These are still variable arguments.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 2):

First; the parameter is read as an
`array of const pointers to const StructType`.

http://cdecl.org/ is a nice place for parsing the rather terse
c/c++ declaration syntax.

The following would work:

```
StructType const * aa[2] = { 0, 0 };
PerformFusionCycle( aa /* rest */ );
```

Comment: What if `aa` is not `const`. Can you cast it to `const * const`? For example, `PerformFusionCycle((const * const)aa /* rest */ );`

Comment: @FiddlingBits - `aa` isn't const here either, it just holds const pointers to const :)

Comment: @StoryTeller It is, isn't it? `StructType const * const aa[2] = { 0, 0 };`. Most likely, `PerformFusionCycle` is defining arguments as `const` because it doesn't modify them. The restriction shouldn't be on the caller.

Comment: @FiddlingBits - *" It is, isn't it?"* The elements of the array are const, not the array. I know it sound weird, but the [standard says so](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p9)

Comment: @StoryTeller Okay, I think I got you. You're saying the `const * const` has a redundant `const`. `aa` is `const` because it's an array (i.e. `aa++` is illegal.).

Comment: @FiddlingBits - That's not what I said. But it's immaterial, I was simply nitpicking at a possible meaning of your comment. No matter.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry, I was mixing up yours and `KonstantinL`'s comments.

Comment: Not quite: the first parameter is read as a *pointer to* `const` pointer to `const StructType`.  Context matters here -- function parameters are *never* arrays, and function parameter declarations of forms that in other contexts would declare arrays instead declare pointers.  But the corresponding actual argument can be the pointer obtained from decay of an array value.

Answer (score 2):

Const-correctness with pointer-to-pointers is very confusing in general. However, this function has gone out of hand. It has gone past const-correctness, which is good programming practice, into abusing the `const` keyword for little or no reason.

```
StructType const* const a[]
```

Here you probably just want to make sure that the function cannot modify the pointer-to-pointed-at data. Nothing else makes sense in a function prototype. The array syntax is not helpful either, because it will get adjusted to a pointer anyhow. Replace all of this with `const StructType** a`.

```
const float32 c,
```

Making variables passed by value `const` is not meaningful. It is a local copy anyway, so who cares if it is modified by the function? Typically this only serves to confuse the programmer. And in my experience, such code is often a pretty certain indication that the original programmer was confused.

Similarly `StructType3 * const d` is not meaningful either. The pointer itself is passed by value, who cares if the function modifies the local copy?

A call for sanity with const-correctness preserved would look like this:

```
void PerformFusionCycle( const StructType** a,
                         const StructType2* b,
                         float32 c,
                         StructType3* d,
                         StructType3* e)
```

Comment: `Making variables passed by value const is not meaningful. It is a local copy anyway, so who cares if it is modified by the function?` very wrong. It makes perfect sense to declare unmodifiable local variable and value-passed arguments as const.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I almost always explain the reasons for downvoting. So see above.

Comment: @SergeyA - It's better SO netiquette to comment and cast your vote in the same small epoch. Leads to less confusion anyway.

Comment: @SergeyA I've had this debate so many times before and never heard any sound rationale from the const-spammers. Of course you don't either, you just say "it makes perfect sense because I say so". So I take it that everytime you declare a plain pointer anywhere in your program, you declare it as `auto signed int* const ptr` rather than `int* ptr`? If not, your coding style is inconsistent.

Comment: I completely agree that the prototype goes way overboard with `const`ness. With respect to parameter `a`, however, it is plausible that the function wants to accept a (`const`ness-irrelevant) pointer to a series of one or more `const` pointers to `const` data.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The problem which such function interfaces is that you can't use them generically. Suppose that you have an array of pointers to const data. But the function expects an array of const pointers to data. Then you can't use the function without casting to `const type* const`, which looks quite weird and is hard to understand.

Comment: That being said, there are actually valid uses of `type * const` function interfaces, and that is the very special case of embedded systems that need to store pointers in true NVM. Functions using such pointers from flash need to have `type* const` parameters, because "casting away" qualifiers in C is not well-defined behavior. But that valid argument is never raised in these debates, the const-spammers always mention subjective, muddled style concerns as the reason.

Comment: @Lundin, what do you mean? Yes, I always declare unmodifiable variables `const`. Helps me to catch nasty errors. If I had my way, **all** variables would be const by default, with explicit `mutable` for mutables.

Comment: @SergeyA I'd hate to maintain that code and would probably resign from the maintenance job upon reading your first line of code: `const int main (const int argc, const char * const argv[])`.

Comment: @Lundin, nope, because `const int` as a return value is not right anyways, and the second argument violates standard for `main` prototype. So you won't find code like this in my program.

Comment: @Lundin, the reason the function might intentionally be declared to accept a series of `const` pointers to `const` data is that that's what is actually expected.  In other words, to avoid having to cast *away* `const`ness of the pointers in the actual argument.  Neither with nor without the intermediate level of `const`ness can the function be used generically in the sense you mean.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of the function is a pointer to a (possibly first of several) const pointer(s) to const `StructType`. So a possible valid argument for `a` can be constructed as follows:

```
struct StructType const   orig[3] = { {} ,{} , {} };
struct StructType const * a[] = {
    orig, orig + 1, orig + 2
};

PerformFusionCycle(a, /* Other arguments */);
```

Comment: This will definitely work although, I think you'll want an initializer to assign the values in your `orig` array.

Comment: @BrianParry - Why not. Although seeing as we know nothing about the structure, it's not too meaningful anyway. I kept it out for brevity, now back in.